# Why does the fullscreen button go missing in Firefox?

Tags: macos, fullscreen

Sometimes in MacOS Ventura 13.2, I notice that the close, minimize, and fullscreen buttons on Firefox are missing. The only way I know to get them back is to exit the browser and open it again.

Is this a bug or a feature I'm triggering by accident?

Normal:

[image]

With buttons missing:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## It's a Bug

I just figured out that if I right-click the top of the window, it gives me the option to "Exit Full Screen Mode". Doing this restores the buttons. So somehow the window stops taking up the whole screen (probably something to do with sleep / wake with my multi-monitor setup) but is still rendered without the buttons as if it were in Full Screen Mode.

I don't know if this is a bug with MacOS or Firefox, but I haven't seen it with any other app yet.

Comment: Drawing those controls is up to the application developer for future reference. Nice solution to a very well stated question - love the photos showing this in action.